# Getting information into eval from fk(primary key)?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Not sure if it is well formed question but perhaps someone has better idea.

[image: description]

So I got something like this /\

My concern is about fk_user_id,  When I'm selectin * from this table I can

```
  `<%# Eval("fk_user_id") %>`
```

And as you guess in result I got some kind of id number.. Is there possibility to somehow take out informations from fk_user table, I would like for example get out of it user_name.

You know mainly I want it for the name of authot, when someone is writing a post it shows the name of the author who wrote it aka fk_user_id.. but I want somehow to show the name of the authot nor his ID.

Halp :<

@EDIT

This is what I have in .cs  to select things from that table in show it in reapeater `        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    cmd.Connection = conn;

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY post_id DESC";
    conn.Open();
    Repeater_Posts.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    Repeater_Posts.DataBind();
    conn.Close();`
```

Comment: You would have to JOIN on the Users table using the foreign user id key.  Once you have wrote that SQL query you would have to use it in your data access layer (If you have one) and retrieve the information that way.  As a start post the code you have.

Comment: @DarrenDavies added code to post, not sure if this is what you meant

Comment: This column fk_user_id is a Foreign Key, meaning that column is used to reference another table. What table is fk_user_id a Foreign Key for?

Comment: @Kramb registered users, where you have things like user_name, user_email, user_password and user_id, which is fk_user_id in posts table

Comment: What is the Primary Key for the registered_users table?

Comment: @Kramb http://i.imgur.com/v3cevbe.png  this?

Comment: Yea, that's it. I've posted the sql that will get you the user_name for all of the rows in posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get all of the user's names from the table registered_users

```
SELECT r.user_name 
FROM posts p INNER JOIN
registered_users r ON p.fk_user_id = r.user_id
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC
```

Comment: Can I ask what r./p. statment means?

Comment: renaming the tables for easier access. p is posts r is for registered_users